# Adding to cart shows "there are no products in your shopping cart"?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, ubercart

If I am logged in, and I click on "buy now", it takes me to the shopping cart where I can checkout. However, if I'm not logged in and I click on "buy now", it says:

> There are no products in your shopping cart.

You can test it by going to http://www.nordbruch.org and clicking on Buy Now anywhere.

Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be due :

1. If your website is recently migrated :
   Then There must be problem with your mysql database . Try checking your "users" table in the database and see if the anonymous user uid is SET to  0, if not then make it 0 .
2. SSL problem like you are using secure-pages etc module..
   You can try setting the $base_url variable in your settings.php file.

You can try re-importing the database or you can import it to your local machine to check if its working there or not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Someone deleted the user with id = 0. Thanks!

Comment: I had base_url and user 0 both properly set.  I had to clear the sessions table and then everything worked.  Any idea how I can keep this from happening again?

Answer (score 0):

If you can add products to shopping cart while you are logged in, then the functionality works fine.

It could be a permission issue. I have a very limited experience with `ubercart`. Try to go to `admin/people/permission` and check if anonymous users have the permission to add to cart (or whatever ubercart calls it).

Comment: I had a look and there doesn't seem to be a permission for this.